# Android shape transformation of View

Tags: android, android-animation, transformation

I wanna create transforming animation of the shape of `View`. For example changing `rectangle` to `oval`. I tried to do this in the same way with color animation:

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.RED), new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)};
TransitionDrawable drawable = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    drawable.startTransition(1000);
    image.setBackground(drawable);
```

But when I tried to do it with `ShapeDrawable[]` I could no shaping transformation, but `imageView` became black.

```
 float[] outerR = new float[] {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    ShapeDrawable oval = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    ShapeDrawable rect = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, null, null));
    rect.setBounds(0,0,120,120);
    oval.setBounds(0,0,120,120);
    ShapeDrawable [] draws = {rect, oval};

    TransitionDrawable drawable = new TransitionDrawable(draws);
    drawable.startTransition(1000);
    image.setBackground(drawable);
```

So is there any programmatical way in Android  to  transform (change the shape of)  `View`  smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try android.view.ViewAnimationUtils but it only works above api 19.

[Example](http://github.com/XunMengWinter/CircularAnim)